# Simple SML code error

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I have just started learning SML and still in the process of making sense of its error messages.

when trying to input the function definition below

```
val rec : real->real = fn 0.0 => 0.0 | n:real => 1.0/n;
```

i get the following error :

```
stdIn:25.9-25.17 Error: syntax error: deleting  COLON ID ARROW
stdIn:25.24-25.33 Error: syntax error: deleting  FN REAL DARROW
stdIn:25.38 Error: syntax error found at BAR
```

can someone point out what i am doing wrong ?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors in your code:

1. Between `val rec` and the type annotation there should be the name of the value you're defining.
2. You can't use pattern matching on `real`s. Since `real`s are inexact, they aren't equality types, so you can't use `=` on them either. You need to use `Real.==` to compare reals for equality (or better: don't compare them for equality, but compare them against some delta instead).

Comment: hello sepp2k. thank for the answer. I checked the real signatures and found the "==" function you mentioned. i am though still not clear on point 1 you mentioned .. is 'rec' a keyword in SML (i just chose it as a short form for reciprocal)

Comment: @ankit: Yes, `rec` is a keyword - it allows a value definition to be recursive.

Comment: perfect. makes sense now that i have read the chapter on recursive functions ... thank you for all the help !